# Restrict access to all URIs except several, Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to restrict the access to all URIs except several ones.

The following URIs can be access freely: `"/", "/login", "/register"`

Any others can be accessed by passing authenticated procedure.

Here is the code that has to restrict access to all URIs except the `"/", "/login", "/register"` (I have found it on StackOverflow):

```
   @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContextConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getBCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
                .and();

        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard");

        http.logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I generate get request (i.e. click on the following link `<a href="/register">Register</a>`) the login page is being displayed. However, it should simply display the registration JSP page.

What did I make wrong? And how can I properly restrict access to all URIs except the several ones?

Part from my auth controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processUserRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") Customer customer,
                                          BindingResult result,
                                          Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        }
        if (customerRepository.checkIfEmailExistsInDatabase(customer.getEmail())) {
            result.rejectValue("email", "email_exist", "Email is in DB");
            return "register";
        }
        if (customerRepository.checkIfLoginExistsInDb(customer)) {
            result.rejectValue("login", "login_exists", "Login is in DB");
            return "register";
        }
        customer.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(customer.getPassword()));
        customerRepository.insert(customer);
        model.addAttribute("user", customer);
        if (customer.getCustomerType().getTypeName().equals("BUSINESS")) {
            model.addAttribute("gasstation", new GasStation());
            return "redirect:add_gasstation";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("vehicle", new Vehicle());
            return "redirect:add_vehicle";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am just wondering if your configuration is being read at all or not. Could you confirm that you have `@Configuration` annotation on your class defining the `configure` method?

Comment: Do you mean @Configuration on a class that defines the spring security context? If yes, then I have it.

Comment: Seems like a context issue can you try this instead `<a href="<c:url value="/register"/>">Register</a>` ?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. The config looks all good, that is why I asked. The other thing is that `and()` function call in the end of your config. I do not see the reason for having that there.

Comment: @M4ver1k, I have tried your approach - no result.

Comment: @GergelyBacso, I have removed `.and()` - didn't help either.

Comment: I was just wondering if you have managed to solve this in the end?